# Issue using ng new to create a new project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

```
/ Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.2: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.12: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ball":"https://regist'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-04T11_34_38_434Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.

The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

I tried to resolve this by using:

1. `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
2. `npm cache verify`
3. `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

But its not working

My version of angular:

```
 Angular CLI: 9.1.4
 Node: 12.16.3
 OS: win32 x64
```

Comment: Please add to the question of the process you followed to generate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue with angular-cli-9. You can try downgrading your angular CLI to version 8.This worked for me

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm i -g @angular/cli@8.3.26
```